# How to block referral traffic without .htaccess?

Tags: traffic, blogger, referrer, spam-blocker

I'm getting a lot of spam referral traffic on blogger, I searched for a way to block this traffic but I need to edit the .htaccess file which I don't have access to on blogger.

Are there any other ways to block this traffic ?
on blogger I can only edit the robots.txt file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're referencing Blogger (`blogger.com`)?

[Referer spam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spam) has been a problem on Blogger and other blogging sites for a very long time. Unfortunately there isn't an effective way to block it because it's very difficult to distinguish legitimate referers from spammers.

Editing your *robots.txt* file will not help because spammers often use fake user-agent strings and do not observe the [robots.txt protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard).

Referer spam will not impact third-party statistics/analytics however, as discussed below, so use one to view actual traffic reports:

[Referer Spam Does Not Represent Real Traffic, To Our Blogs](http://blogging.nitecruzr.net/2011/07/referer-spam-is-annoying-and-its.html)

The most common advice given is:

- Do not publish the contents of your traffic logs or list referers in your content.
- Do not click on links in your traffic logs that you don't recognize.
- Be patient and let Google (or other blog service) block referer spam over time.

Comment: Does it impact the site rank on Google ?

Comment: Not at all, Google is keenly aware of this issue.

Comment: Sure thing. It's a common concern for blog users, and the simple advice is just ignore it.