# Strange domains as a blog's traffic sources

Tags: search-engines, google-adsense, advertising, traffic, blogger

Watching my Blogspot analytics i saw several strange-looking domains, like
bd053ac3.any.gs and others. So trying to identify them i got the following:

bd053ac3.any.gs - shows "Link not found" page
any.gs, dyo.gs - goes to linkbucks.com

Yes, my blog uses AdSense, but i don't advertise it. So i wanted to understand why this can happen?

[image: Blog traffic sources]

Comment: Have a look the answer here regarding unrecognized referrers in blogs: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52098/how-to-block-referral-traffic-without-htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called referrer spam.  Nobody is actually viewing your blog from these sites - and nobody knows about these links but you, since only you can see your Stats logs.  There are no links to your blog, from these websites.

Don't click on the links in your Stats logs.  That's the only way to make referrer spam stop.

http://blogging.nitecruzr.net/2012/04/referer-spam-cannot-be-blocked.html

Answer (score 0):

The network Link Bucks is referring traffic to your blog and these are the dynamically generated URL's that they pass visitors via.

I really wouldn't worry about it unless any of these visitors are doing anything malicious on your site - which is unlikely as it's just a low quality garbage network that pays it's members to share links and generate referrals.